# Is $\sqrt[n]{x^n} = |x|$ for all n?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

We know that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. My question is:

> Does this property apply to $\sqrt[n]{x^n}$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I can't think on how i could check this. It is not very clear to me why $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ either.
Thank you.

Comment: No. What about $\sqrt[3]{-1}$?

Comment: What happens for $n=1$ or $n=3$?

Comment: For even $n$, we define $\sqrt[n]\cdot : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ and it would follow the given rule. Do you see why we don't need to do this for odd $n$?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}$ always gives you back the non-negative number whose square is $x^2$, i.e, whichever of $x,-x$ is non-negative. But this is $|x|$'s job too.

Comment: It's true for all positive x and all even n.  For odd n and negative x the nth root is simply x and not |x|.

Comment: It is true for $x = n \ge 0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. For a counterexample $\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$

For even $n$, we define $\sqrt[n]{x}$ to be $\ge 0$ because we want $\sqrt[n]{x}$ to work like a function. That is, if we said "$\sqrt[n]{x}$ is that  $y$ such that $y^n =x$", then we would get 2 solutions for $y$ for even $n$, but for it to work like a function we want just one. This is why $\sqrt[2]{x^2} = |x|$, rather than $\sqrt[2]{x^2}=\pm x$

Comment: Yea, i was thinking that it would only work for even numbers. It seems obvious now. Thank you.

Comment: Although technically in the complex numbers, there would be three cube roots of $ -8 $ if I am not mistaken. Not that it changes the validity.

Answer (score 3):

Big picture:

For any real number $y$, there are $n $ *complex* numbers , $k $so that $k^n=y$. These are the $n $ complex roots.

If $n $ is odd then exactly one of the roots is real.  We call that one "the" $n-th $ root of $y$.  If $y $ is negative/positive then $\sqrt [n]{y}$ is negative/positive.

So if $n$ is odd $\sqrt {x^n}=x$.

If $n$ is even and $y $ is positive, two of these roots will be real.  One will be positive real and one will be negative real.  By convention we call the *positive* one "the" $n-th $ root of $y $.

So if $n $ is even  then $x^n $ will always be positive (even if $x $ is negative) and will have *two* real $n-th $ roots; a positive one equal to $|x|$, and a negative one equal to $-|x|$.  By convention, only the *positive* one is considered "the" $n-th $ root.

So if $n $ is even $\sqrt [n]{x^n}=|x|$.

Finally, if $n$ is even but $y $ is negative then none of the roots are real.  There are no real even roots of a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

No, for $n$ is odd is not true.

Comment: @William why    so ?

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance,  $\sqrt[3]{(-1)^3} = \sqrt[3]{-1} = -1$ .